# Can't Access Linux Boot After Resizing Partition (Ubuntu 16.04)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, partitioning

I'll try and keep this as concise as possible, here are the order of events:

1) New PC, has Windows on it.

2) I installed Ubuntu on my new PC

3) I disabled Secure Boot so that I could use proprietary Nvidia drivers (I was prompted to do this)

4) I needed more space on my Ubuntu FS so I boot up the Gparted Live Disk

5) I resize my FS, growing it to fill unallocated space

6) Operation successful, shutdown PC and boot up into Ubuntu

And now everytime I boot Ubuntu

1) I am prompted to cancel a system filecheck with ctrl + c (I do not cancel it)

2) I see this:

> Please enter passphrase for disk ST1000DM003-12B102 (cryptswap1) on none!

There is a box below it that looks like I can enter text, but nothing seems to happen when I type or press enter. I did not set up any sort of "cryptswap", I don't even know what that is. Does anyone know what is happening or how I can get around this? I need to access my Ubuntu install for work so this is really freaking me out. Worse case scenario I guess I could reinstall it but I would lose a lot of time and work so I'm hoping there is another solution

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this, in case anyone else like me is seeing a message about cryptswap after resizing a partition with Gparted here is the solution:

1) Boot up Gparted Live Disc again

2) Select the partition labeled "linux-swap", take note of it's name and right click and delete it.

3) Right click the unallocated space, select new, give it the same name and set the type to "linux-swap". If "linux-swap" isn't an option, you can make it ext4 and then format it to linux-swap afterwards.

Then it will work! Ubuntu took quite a bit longer to boot (~20secs longer) but just stick with it and everything will run smoothly.

Comment: and for slow bootup, you can check [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/744478/696880)